# Create Modulable UI

Tags: android, user-interface, view

I have some questions about construction of UI (I developp with the API 10 and I haven't the choice).
I am buidling a modular application,my goal is to create independant module.
Indeed, each module "wake up" when the "catch the good event" (via broadcast receiver/intentfilter). I have made a Service which start and launch module. Modules does its task.
My UI application is divided in three part (header, content and bottom).
The header and bottom are never modified during the life of the application and the content is variable.
Each module can be associated with UI and they modify the content's display.

For example, each module is associated with a layout file ( MyModule.xml).
The goal is to display the view of MyModule.xml instead of content.

So how to create a dynamic UI ?

Sorry for my english.
Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would explore [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html). You can have a header fragment, footer fragment, and fragments for each of your modules.

Comment: Thanks for your response but the API 10 doesn't support fragments (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html). If you have a link that explain how to similar mechanism fragment with an API lower than 11.